# Подключение / отключение Rails Mountable Engine во время работы сайта

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Я получил задание написать корпоративный портал как курсовой проект. Одно из требований - подключение модулей в панели администратора. Как это сделать на Rails?

Comment: ну и как, получилось? много работаю с Engines и уверен, что без перезагрузки сервера на лету вы модуль не подключите/отключите